# CSS aling items in the same row

Tags: css

I'm trying to aling items in the same row.

I would to obtain the button in the center and the legend in the right part ( near the end of the page)

```css
.legendContainer {
  // padding: 10px
  // display: flex; 
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  // margin-left: 10px;
}

.legend {
  list-style: none;
}

.legend li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.legend span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.legend .KO {
  background-color: #FFA8A8;
}

.legend .aOK {
  background-color: #B6FFCE;
}

.legend .send {
  background-color: #F6FFA4;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center ">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 70px;">
    <button>Offers</button>
    <button>Opportunity</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 140px">
    <div class="legendContainer" *ngIf="tableOffer">
      <ul class="legend">
        <div class="legendTitle">Legend</div>
        <li><span class="KO"></span> KO</li><br>
        <li><span class="Send"></span>Send</li><br>
        <li><span class="OK"></span> OK</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using padding but on mobile device it isn't look good.

Comment: Please can you explain better your desider result?

Comment: Yes on the same row I would to obtain the two button on the center, and the "legend" in the right (near the end of page)

Comment: you just want them in a  single row

Comment: yes in only a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
Removed the big style paddings: `style="padding-left: 70px;"`, `style="padding-left: 140px"` from the divs. `div.row` first child and `.legendcontainer` with `width: fit-content;` to fit their content and `margin-left: auto`, (`.ms-auto`) so they move to the end. Changed the `.col` of the buttons div  to `col-8` (60% big) and the legend container to `col-4` (40% big). Bootstrap max col size (and default if its not defined) is 12 (8+4).

```css
.legendContainer {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.legend {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.legend li {
  float: left;
}

.legend span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.legend .KO {
  background-color: #FFA8A8;
}

.legend .aOK {
  background-color: #B6FFCE;
}

.legend .send {
  background-color: #F6FFA4;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row flex-row justify-content-center w-100 align-items-center">
  <div class="col-8 ms-auto p-0" style="width:fit-content;">
    <button>Offers</button>
    <button>Opportunity</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="legendContainer" *ngIf="tableOffer">
      <ul class="legend">
        <div class="legendTitle">Legend</div>
        <li><span class="KO"></span> KO</li><br>
        <li><span class="Send"></span>Send</li><br>
        <li><span class="OK"></span> OK</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your code please

Comment: not in the comments... please update your answer

Answer (score 0):

Buttons in the center. And the legend on the right.

```css
.btns {
  text-align: center;
}
.legendContainer {
  /*padding: 10px*/
  display: flex; 
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;;
  /*margin-left: 10px;*/
  xbackground: gray;
}
.legendContainer ul {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.legend {
  list-style: none;
}

.legend li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.legend span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.legendTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.legend .KO {
  background-color: #FFA8A8;
}

.legend .aOK {
  background-color: #B6FFCE;
}

.legend .send {
  background-color: #F6FFA4;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center ">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 btns" style="">
    <button>Offers</button>
    <button>Opportunity</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 140px">
    <div class="legendContainer" *ngIf="tableOffer">
      
      <ul class="legend">        
        <div class="legendTitle">Legend</div>
        <li><span class="KO"></span> KO</li><br>
        <li><span class="Send"></span>Send</li><br>
        <li><span class="OK"></span> OK</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

legend to display: inline;, or float the li left or right. Additionally, you can also use display:flex; on the ul

```css
.legendContainer {
  
}

.legend {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  list-style-type:none;
  float: left;
  
}

.legend li {
/*   float: left; */
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}

.legend span {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  
}

.legendTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.legend .KO {
  background-color: #FFA8A8;
}

.legend .aOK {
  background-color: #B6FFCE;
}

.legend .send {
  background-color: #F6FFA4;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center ">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 70px;">
    <button>Offers</button>
    <button>Opportunity</button>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 140px">
    <div class="legendContainer" *ngIf="tableOffer">
      <ul class="legend">
        <div class="legendTitle">Legend</div>
        <li><span class="KO"></span> KO</li><br>
        <li><span class="Send"></span>Send</li><br>
        <li><span class="OK"></span> OK</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```